# what would be a good approach for multithreading recursive traversal over directory tree?

Tags: java, python

I'm thinking of a good approach for multithreaded recursive traversal over a directory tree.

What I'm doing right now is taking a the folders under a root directory and running a recursive traversal on each folder in a separate thread.

This improved the performance quite a bit, but I still have a "long tail" problem - large folders take a lot of time.

What approach would be better than this?

I'm using python and java for this.

thanks.

EDIT:
I don't need to load the files into memrory. just handle the file paths and maybe take some metadata info  like file size.

Comment: show some code / what have you tried? / what exactly is the question?

Comment: Not sure what you have tried before, but are you loading the files into memory first? It might be an I/O issue. If you have not tried it yet, load the folders into memory first.

Comment: What's your policy on spawning threads? If you just spawn a new thread for each subdirectory, you will very quickly become I/O bound, reducing each thread to a grind, and then will still keep spawning more threads for each directory you DO manage to see which will grind your whole machine to a halt.

Comment: I've wrote that I tried: taking the directories under a given root dir, and running the traversal code on each folder in a seperate therad. The question is - are there better approaches for multithreading this task?

Comment: 1. no, I dont need to load the files into memroy. just handle the file paths.
2. I did try it. I've seen great improvement when running jsut in one thread comparing to running each 2-level folder on a different thread.

Comment: that depends on the Threading Ipmlementation. If you use Sun's VM on a Windows Machine, there is actually always one process and one Thread. The VM then does the multi Threading itself by switching from Java Thread to Java Thread. But since there is only one system Thread IO is limited. My suggestion would be, to use a limited number of Threads and try changing that: E.g. your application defines that it has 10 Threads, then uses these Threads to read the directories. If one Thread finishes a directory, it would get the next one from a queue and read it.

Comment: also the timeconsuming thing might be your code (what you do with the files and how you access them) and not the actual file listings.

Comment: if you use python AND java, it means you are spawning java processes from python processes or the other way round? spawning processes by invoking programs is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @kw4nta -  this is exactly what I'm doing. It works fine. the only problem is that if I have some folders that are a lot more bigger than other folder, I'll read to the end of the process and have only few threads doing traversal over the big folders,, while I have free threads in the pool.

Comment: @kw4nta - no, I meant that I've written apps to do what I said both in java and python.

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrong approach, since you don't know the depth and size of the directory nodes. Even if you knew, **Iteration itself** over the directory tree wouldn't be sped up by doing it in multiple threads. What you want to do is iterate over the directories in a single thread and submit the work you are doing on files/directories to a [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).
Also see [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Comment: The thing is that I only need to collect the file paths and maybe some metadata. Performance IS an issue here because I have tens of millions of files. From what I've seen, running the iteration on a single thread, take much longer than my approach. But still, lets say that I use 15 threads, and the while process takes 20 minutes (instead of 60 minutes single-threaded) - 8 minutes of these 20, are spent only by 5 threads on very big directories. because all other threads have finished.

Comment: Now I'm curious. On first iteration over the files it should simply be IO bound and depend on seek time. On second iteration, on a sane OS at least, everything should be in the cache. Could you rerun your benchmark without accessing any metadata at all and just collect the file path? Because I tried with the Fork/Join API (Java 7) and only got worse numbers with multiple threads. Also, running in a Profiler might be interesting to see where exactly the time is spent.

Comment: 1. what cache are you talking about?
2. should be noted that the paths are network paths - \\server1\path...
so maybe the network overhead causes more threads to be more efficient.

Comment: 1. Directory Cache of the VFS 2. Ok, didn't think about network FS. The Fork/Join API might be for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, strictly answering the multithreading question, you could come up with some rule for when in the recursion you spin off new threads, for example, every even populated depth gets split into threads. Observe, in Python-esque pseudocode:

```
depth = 0
while true:
    subDirCount = countSubDirs()
    if subDirCount = 0:
        break
    else:
        if depth % 2 = 0:
            for dir in subDirs:
                newThread(dir)
        else:
            for dir in subDirs:
                recurse(dir)
```

Now this solution doesn't deal with the *horrible* time you'll have with [thread-safety](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html). This is as good a setup for wonky asynchronous returns as you're going to get.